# Start Squid Cache Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, squid, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having trouble starting squid.

I type in console

```
squid -k shutdown
```

and get:

```
squid: ERROR: Could not send signal 15 to process 2065: (3) No such process
```

I have checked and process "2065" does not found.

I'm using Squid Cache: Version 3.1.19.

I have checked google and couldn't find anything that would work?

Any ideas? Actuality can't start the squid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm removed:

```
sudo rm /var/run/squid3.pid
```

stop/start service
    sudo service squid3 stop
    sudo service squid3 start

and I solved whith it.